# Join mining pool with Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, mining-pools

I followed [this guide](https://github.com/angelomilan/ethereum-guides/blob/master/GPU-cloud_mining.md) to set up aws to mine ethereum with an instance that has GPUs. After set up, I let the miner go for a day without any pay in the smallest denomination of Ethereum. I researched and found that, at this point, you should be mining with a pool. I searched around, but found no instructions of how to mine in a pool with Geth.

Can someone help me find out the right way to join a mining pool using geth?

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

You don't need geth to mine with a pool, just Ethminer.

Simply do `ethminer --opencl-device 0 -G -F "POOL_ADDRESS"`

You will need to look at the documentation for your pool to find the proper URL for the "POOL_ADDRESS" field.

For example, if you wanted to mine on dwarfpool, you would use `ethminer -G -F http://eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:80/YOUR_WALLET` where `YOUR_WALLET` is the address you would like to receive payouts at.

Comment: Is `ethminer` a part of official etherum toolset? It lives in another github repo `https://github.com/ethereum-mining`. Where is the backstory? Sorry for a random question.

Comment: It's kind of hard to say what the "official" Ethereum toolset is. When this answer was posted, it reffered to the ethminer in the cpp-ethereum GitHub. It is now separately hosted and developed by respected members of the community, including original contributors to the cpp version

Comment: Is it possible to mine through `geth` since `ethminer` does not allow CPU miners? @Tjaden Hess♦

Comment: This doesn't answer the question